# How to fix aws s3 persinged upload SignatureDoesNotMatch?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I want to take the presigned url of aws s3 and PUT the image.

However, after receiving a presigned url, an error appears when requesting a file PUT with the url.

Please tell me how to fix it. T_T

get signedURL Method.

```
public String getSignedURL(String fileName){

    Date expiration=new Date();
    long expTimeMillis =expiration.getTime();
    expTimeMillis+=1000*60*1; //1Min
    expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

    //+uploadTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy.mm.dd HH:mm:ss z"))

    String objectKey="boardimages/"+fileName; //target.  buket/boardimages/(here my image)
    URL urls=null;
    try {
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest url = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey)
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                .withExpiration(expiration);

        url.addRequestParameter(Headers.S3_CANNED_ACL, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead.toString());
        urls = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(url);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("pre-signed url : "+urls);
    return urls.toString();
}
```

Upload html file

```
<form role="form" action="#" th:action="${url}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="click"></input>
```

Error Message

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
</Message>
```

My s3 Cors.

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "HEAD",
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

All my public access access is inactive.

How to fix it??...

Comment: Have you e.g. gone through https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.11.4/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html ? Your `form` needs to have a lot more fields to work.

Comment: Sorry to ask again. In the post of this post, the key is the object target to be uploaded in s3, and the AWSAccessKeyId is understood as the accesskey of the iam user. Signature and policy don't make sense. Is the signature the secretKey of user iam?  As for the policy, I do not know where to write the json section in the s3 policy. Please teach me.